# Batch Channel Updating - Multiple Fields

Tags: ee2, cartthrob, batch-update

Hi Im looking for advice in either code format or any addons/modules etc available for EE2.

I have a channel that is set out as follows

Title
Description
Price 1
Price 2
Price 3
Price 4
Category:  (A,B,C,D)
Actual Price:

I want to be able to batch adjust the price of Price 1,2,3,4 depending on changes with the supplier of the equipment either across the board or dependent on 1 category.

I know I can do it with normally with PHP, but is there a better way built in to EE or a hybrid php/ee option?

Answer (score 2):

You can use DataGrab (http://brandnewbox.co.uk/support/category/datagrab/) or Importer (http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/importer/) module for the batch updating the entries.

I think, these module would be better solution rather than having any other.